# In what sense does Allah love the poor?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, backbiting

I read a Hadith where apparently the prophet said ‘cause me to live amongst the poor and cause me to die poor’, is this correct?

Firstly who do we consider fitting into the category of poor is it beggars like you find in third world countries?

I’m in the U.K. and there’s council
Estates here where people are on welfare benefits but the government gives them enough to have their necessities.  They are uneducated and without luxuries.

Their young stay out in the streets involved in gangs while the adults spend all their time gossiping and backbiting others in the community - even people they don’t know.

Are such people considers poor and in what way does Allah love them?  If I was poor I wouldn’t spend my time gossiping about others because I have no life.  However it seems poor communities love to do this as they are idle and struggling.  Should we really be praying to live and die amongst people like this??!!

On the other hand is Allah talking about the extremely poor who I don’t know hope they live.

What’s special about the poor people that The prophet prayed to be like and Among them.  If it’s they have more remembrance of Allah, then why do they spend all day long just inventing and gossiping, and even causing conflicts about other people in the community?

Wasalam

Answer (score 0):

Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him was given choice to live with luxurious of the world or live like humble servant . He chose to live like a  humble servant . He was a firm believer of Allah and he knew this world was a temporary, a test and he will be rewarded paradise here after. He did not have attachment to the world .  Also he had contentment of the heart which he was in no need of wealth of this world . He was here to spread a message just like prophets before him .

As a prophet he loved all mankind , he loved believers , unbelievers , poor , wealthy . If he ever read about his life , all his life was based on uniting mankind . He is final sermon he said that we are servants of Allah and there is no superiority over another .

Answer (score 0):

Also I want to add prophet Muhammad ( peace be upon him ) always encouraged believers to make your way in this world . Go out and prosper . Do trade and live well if you can . He never said be poor but he encouraged not to be greedy and have attachments to worldly life . How many people you know who will only feel secure if they have bank accounts at certain number ? I know personally many that they believe contentment only achieved through money . That is perfect example how deluded and how materialistic humans can get .

He never encouraged believers to be idle and cause corruption. Communities you are talking about in England and in America exists in many parts . Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him was kind to poor and helped them and encouraged his believers to treat them kindly , do not look down on them , if you have means of helping to raise them from poverty and do your charities in secret so they don’t feel bad .
Many people nowadays feel they are superior or better human beings because they are wealthy. It is human nature to claim superiority whether you are wealthy, better looking , have lighter skin. Royals for example . Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him only said to humankind that we are all equals and to treat them with kindness

Comment: If you want to add information to your existing answer, just use the "Edit" link on that post instead of posting a new answer.